# Can't add multiple lines with different font sizes in one div

Tags: html, css

I would like to add multi text in one of the divs, the second line should not be bold as the first, but it is, and texts must be aligned vertically in the center of the div.

```css
.divProp {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 90px;
  border-color: #CCCCCC;
  border-width: thin;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 15px;
  min-width: 100px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.divProp>p {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.noneBold {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="divProp">
        <p>DIV 1</p>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <div class="divProp">
        <p>DIV 2</p>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <div class="divProp">
        <p>LONG TEXT DIV 3</p>
        <p class="noneBold">Sub Div 3</p>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <div class="divProp">
        <p>DIV 4</p>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <div class="divProp">
        <p>DIV 5</p>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Sub Div 3** is outside the div but it should be second line under **Div 3**

[image]

Comment: Your `line-height` is pushing the content outside of the div.

Comment: But if i don't add line-height how can i make sure that the text in the center of the div?

Comment: There are multiple ways to vertically center content. You can use flexbox, or just set a specified padding to the top of your divs. CSS Tricks: (https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide).

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments by @HunterTurner, your `line-height` is causing each new line to be `90px` apart. If you wish to add space around your text I would use `padding` instead as this does not affect each line but the element the lines are contained in.

EDIT: After reading your comment I updated the css to center both horizontally and vertically. I used flexboxes for this, if you wish to learn more about the power of flexboxes I would look [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
.divProp {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 90px; /* Using padding instead */
  border-color: #CCCCCC;
  border-width: thin;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 15px;
  min-width: 100px;
  word-wrap: break-word;

  /* Center Vertically */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.divProp p {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: auto; /* Center horizontally */
}

.noneBold {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="divProp">
        <p>DIV 1</p>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <div class="divProp">
        <p>DIV 2</p>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <div class="divProp">
        <div>
          <p>LONG TEXT DIV 3</p>
          <p class="noneBold">Sub Div 3</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <div class="divProp">
        <p>DIV 4</p>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <div class="divProp">
        <p>DIV 5</p>

      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Just a word of advice, it appears you are trying to put together a grid. There are many open source projects that provide this grid functionality and allow for quick and easy responsive layouts, something you won't get from using tables. I would recommend http://getbootstrap.com/ but there are many others out there.

Comment: Thank you Lee, I just have to edit one table and i cannot reference to bootstrap or any thing else as i'm not allowed.
Just question, when i copy your code, all lines seems to be in one line
i even tried to add <br/> after the first line with no sucess, any idea

Comment: Flexboxes look for the first child element. I wrapped the two `p` in a `div` so flexbox would treat them as one. My guess is you need to do this as well.

Comment: Sorry i can't follow, should i wrap both P in one div? i already did but i guess i'm missing something. i will do some research, thanks :-)

Comment: Yes they should be wrapped up in a single `div` external to the `div` with the class `divProp`. If you look at the html in the answer I have wrapped the `p` for the multiline section twice.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the bold problem, `.divProp > p` is more specific than `.noneBold` and so the first overrides the second.

You can either find another way to target the default case, or simply add extra specificity to the .noneBold declaration:

```
.divProp > p.noneBold {
    font-weight: normal; /* will apply */
}
```

```css
.divProp {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-color: #CCCCCC;
  border-width: thin;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 15px;
  min-width: 100px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.divProp>p {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.divProp>p.noneBold {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="divProp">
        <p>DIV 1</p>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <div class="divProp">
        <p>DIV 2</p>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <div class="divProp">
        <p>LONG TEXT DIV 3</p>
        <p class="noneBold">Sub Div 3</p>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <div class="divProp">
        <p>DIV 4</p>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <div class="divProp">
        <p>DIV 5</p>

      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```